# Firebase App Indexing not showing App in search results for users that don't have this app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-indexing

In documentation for [Firebase App Indexing](https://firebase.google.com/products/app-indexing/) they say that App will be displayed also for users that don't have this app installed.

> New users see an install card for your app in Search results when relevant queries trigger.

or from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/)

> The install button for your app appears next to your homepage search result, giving users an easy path to installing your app to view content.

I tried to see examples from DailyMail, Buzzfeed, Etsy but couldn't. I don't see app install card, or even Instant App link in search results for relevant queries, when I don't have any off these apps.

when app not installed: I don't get any install app button, beside results
[image]

after app installed I can see App icon
[image]

Comment: you got anything on it ?